# Trouble creating a main menu

Tags: android, user-interface, interface, menu

I'm learning how to make android app, and below is the code I'm using to create a main menu. The problem is that it keeps saying "mainmenu cannot be resolved or is not a field."

```
package chapter.seven;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class UserInterface extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need an appropriate file named `mainmenu.xml` in your `res/menu` folder (you may need to create this folder yourself).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you actually have defined a `mainmenu` XML Resource file which contains a proper menu definition.
2. Make sure there are no errors in your layouts and XML Resource files. This could prevent the R file from being generated correctly.
3. Refresh / Clean the project

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Paul said, import the application resource file if the class is not in the same package as the app's declared package:

```
import chapter.seven.R;
```

Comment: I disagree, you do not need to explicitly import this file.

Comment: @Sam, for the sake of testing, open a project in Eclipse, comment that line, and you'll see what follows.

Comment: You don't have to import R when the class where you require it is in the same package as the apps declared package - because thats where R will be generated *(this seems to be the case here)*. When your class is found in a subpackage *(e.g. could be chapter.seven.ui.UserInterface here)* you have to add the import.